# G-Sheet Function support to Match Date, name and Other Point

Tags: function, google-sheets

Its Pleasurer if you can support me to write function to preform google sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uwbFcdkN3VHkzpHyx73LSTbPwltZrH5R_n7jsLe-iuU/edit?usp=sharing

Solution starting from cell D7 (D7:AH14)
Need to Factors
For Sheet Working Indika -
Date row 6,
Facility Column C
Plan or Actual - Cell F3 (F3:J3)

Need to Capture Information from Sheet Facility Schedule
Date - Row 2
Facility Column B
Plan or Actual - Column C

[image]

Best regard
Indika

Comment: Please show the expected result you want to get. Also, sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [See How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/15384825)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me know if this is useful:

In D7 use this formula and copy then to the entire range:

```
=index('Facility Schedule'!$1:$962,match($C7,'Facility Schedule'!$B$1:$B$18,0)+if($F$3="Actual",1,0),match(D$6,'Facility Schedule'!$2:$2,0))
```

Here I upload a picture of your own spreadsheet with Plan and Actual displayed:
[image]
[image]
Look how Facility A changes (which is the only one different by now)

Comment: Thanks lot for all support, I tested while changing F3 as Actual and Plan, But it picking only Actual. So Need your support to pick based on that selection as well.
If I Pick Plan need to pick from Plan and if we pick Actual need to pick actual data.
Thanks Lot

Best Regard
Indika

Comment: That was working too with this formula, I'll send you then my sample spreadsheet

Comment: @indikaprasanna I've added an edit with the pictures of your own spreadsheet ;)

Comment: Thanks lot, When I check again it Working well